# How to Update same table on deletion in MYSQL?

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.5, rdbms

In my Database I have a **table**: `Employee` with recursive association, an employee can be boss of other employee.

Following is query I used to create table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Employee` (
  `SSN` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(64) DEFAULT NULL,
  `designation` varchar(128) NOT NULL,
  `MSSN` varchar(64) DEFAULT NULL, 
  PRIMARY KEY (`SSN`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_Manager_Employee`  FOREIGN KEY (`MSSN`) REFERENCES Employee(SSN)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

And I could successfully create my table:

```
mysql> DESCRIBE Employee;
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field       | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| SSN         | varchar(64)  | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| name        | varchar(64)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| designation | varchar(128) | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| MSSN        | varchar(64)  | YES  | MUL | NULL    |       |
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Then I inserted some tuple in Employee table using following query.

```
mysql> INSERT INTO Employee VALUES 
    -> ("1", "A", "OWNER",  NULL), 
    -> ("2", "B", "BOSS",   "1"),
    -> ("3", "C", "WORKER", "2"),
    -> ("4", "D", "BOSS",   "2"),
    -> ("5", "E", "WORKER", "4"),
    -> ("6", "F", "WORKER", "1"),
    -> ("7", "G", "WORKER", "4")
    -> ;
Query OK, 7 rows affected (0.02 sec)
Records: 7  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0
```

Now I have following hierarchical relation among the rows in table:

```
        A
       / \
      B   F
     / \
    C   D
       / \
      G   E
```

Following is Select statement for table:

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM Employee;
+-----+------+-------------+------+
| SSN | name | designation | MSSN |
+-----+------+-------------+------+
| 1   | A    | OWNER       | NULL |
| 2   | B    | BOSS        | 1    |  
| 3   | C    | WORKER      | 2    |  
| 4   | D    | BOSS        | 2    |  
| 5   | E    | WORKER      | 4    |   
| 6   | F    | WORKER      | 1    |  
| 7   | G    | WORKER      | 4    |  
+-----+------+-------------+------+
7 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Now, I want to impose a constraint like : `If any employee (BOSS) deleted then new BOSS of workers under him become immediate BOSS of deleted employee (Old BOSS)`. e.g. If I delete `D` then `B` Become BOSS of `G` and `E`.

For that I also written a **Trigger** as follows:

```
mysql>  DELIMITER $$
mysql>        CREATE
    ->        TRIGGER `Employee_before_delete` BEFORE DELETE
    ->          ON `Employee`
    ->          FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    ->          UPDATE Employee
    ->          SET MSSN=old.MSSN
    ->          WHERE MSSN=old.MSSN; 
    ->        END$$
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.07 sec)

mysql>        DELIMITER ;
```

But When I perform some deletion:

```
mysql> DELETE FROM Employee WHERE SSN='4';
ERROR 1442 (HY000): Can't update table 'Employee' in stored function/trigger
because it is already used by statement which invoked this stored 
function/trigger.
```

I [learn here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1582683/mysql-trigger-stored-trigger-is-already-used-by-statement-which-invoked-stored-t/2314264#2314264) that `this trigger is not possible` because `In MySQL triggers can't manipulate the table they are assigned to`.

Is there some **other possible way to do this?** Can some one suggest me other method ? A suggestion would be enough but should be efficient.

**EDIT:** Is it possible using `Nested Query`?
I also asked it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13487010/how-to-update-same-table-on-deletion-in-mysql).

Comment: `SEE ALSO` **BOTH SOLUTIONS** : http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/29152/which-update-is-faster-using-join-or-sequential

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to delete `D` is to do the following:

- Have `B` inherit `G` and `E`, putting them on the same level as `D`.
- Delete `D`

First, I'll load your sample data

```
mysql> DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS grijesh;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.06 sec)

mysql> CREATE DATABASE grijesh;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> USE grijesh
Database changed
mysql> CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Employee` (
    ->   `SSN` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
    ->   `name` varchar(64) DEFAULT NULL,
    ->   `designation` varchar(128) NOT NULL,
    ->   `MSSN` varchar(64) DEFAULT NULL,
    ->   PRIMARY KEY (`SSN`),
    ->   CONSTRAINT `FK_Manager_Employee`  FOREIGN KEY (`MSSN`) REFERENCES Employee(SSN)
    -> ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.08 sec)

mysql> INSERT INTO Employee VALUES
    -> ("1", "A", "OWNER",  NULL),
    -> ("2", "B", "BOSS",   "1"),
    -> ("3", "C", "WORKER", "2"),
    -> ("4", "D", "BOSS",   "2"),
    -> ("5", "E", "WORKER", "4"),
    -> ("6", "F", "WORKER", "1"),
    -> ("7", "G", "WORKER", "4");
Query OK, 7 rows affected (0.05 sec)
Records: 7  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> SELECT * FROM Employee;
+-----+------+-------------+------+
| SSN | name | designation | MSSN |
+-----+------+-------------+------+
| 1   | A    | OWNER       | NULL |
| 2   | B    | BOSS        | 1    |
| 3   | C    | WORKER      | 2    |
| 4   | D    | BOSS        | 2    |
| 5   | E    | WORKER      | 4    |
| 6   | F    | WORKER      | 1    |
| 7   | G    | WORKER      | 4    |
+-----+------+-------------+------+
7 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

View all current relationships

```
mysql> SELECT
    ->     A.name,A.designation,
    ->     B.name,B.designation
    -> FROM
    ->     `Employee` A INNER JOIN `Employee` B ON A.SSN= B.MSSN
    -> ORDER BY A.SSN,B.SSN
    -> ;
+------+-------------+------+-------------+
| name | designation | name | designation |
+------+-------------+------+-------------+
| A    | OWNER       | B    | BOSS        |
| A    | OWNER       | F    | WORKER      |
| B    | BOSS        | C    | WORKER      |
| B    | BOSS        | D    | BOSS        |
| D    | BOSS        | E    | WORKER      |
| D    | BOSS        | G    | WORKER      |
+------+-------------+------+-------------+
6 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

With this `UPDATE JOIN` query

```
UPDATE `Employee` A INNER JOIN `Employee` B ON A.SSN= B.MSSN
SET B.MSSN = A.MSSN WHERE A.SSN = '4';
```

let's elevate `G` and `E` to the same level as `D` and show relationships

```
mysql> UPDATE `Employee` A INNER JOIN `Employee` B ON A.SSN= B.MSSN
    -> SET B.MSSN = A.MSSN WHERE A.SSN = '4';
Query OK, 2 rows affected (0.06 sec)
Rows matched: 2  Changed: 2  Warnings: 0

mysql> SELECT
    ->     A.name,A.designation,
    ->     B.name,B.designation
    -> FROM
    ->     `Employee` A INNER JOIN `Employee` B ON A.SSN= B.MSSN
    -> ORDER BY A.SSN,B.SSN
    -> ;
+------+-------------+------+-------------+
| name | designation | name | designation |
+------+-------------+------+-------------+
| A    | OWNER       | B    | BOSS        |
| A    | OWNER       | F    | WORKER      |
| B    | BOSS        | C    | WORKER      |
| B    | BOSS        | D    | BOSS        |
| B    | BOSS        | E    | WORKER      |
| B    | BOSS        | G    | WORKER      |
+------+-------------+------+-------------+
6 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

At this point, `D` is nobody's boss.

Now, delete it and show relationships:

```
mysql> DELETE FROM `Employee` WHERE SSN = '4';
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.05 sec)

mysql> SELECT
    ->     A.name,A.designation,
    ->     B.name,B.designation
    -> FROM
    ->     `Employee` A INNER JOIN `Employee` B ON A.SSN= B.MSSN
    -> ORDER BY A.SSN,B.SSN
    -> ;
+------+-------------+------+-------------+
| name | designation | name | designation |
+------+-------------+------+-------------+
| A    | OWNER       | B    | BOSS        |
| A    | OWNER       | F    | WORKER      |
| B    | BOSS        | C    | WORKER      |
| B    | BOSS        | E    | WORKER      |
| B    | BOSS        | G    | WORKER      |
+------+-------------+------+-------------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

Give it a Try !!!

Please notice that you do not need a Trigger

Comment: can't we write `nested query` for this?

Comment: hi answer this also: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/29170/restriction-on-self-referencing-on-insert-in-mysql