# Restriction on self referencing on insert in MYSQL?

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.5, rdbms

How to restrict insert on adding self-referencing rows in a recursive relation table (a table contains foreign key points itself)?

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM Employee;
+-----+------+-------------+------+
| SSN | name | designation | MSSN |
+-----+------+-------------+------+
| 1   | A    | OWNER       | NULL |
| 2   | B    | BOSS        | 1    |
| 3   | C    | WORKER      | 2    |
| 4   | D    | BOSS        | 2    |
| 5   | E    | WORKER      | 4    |
| 6   | F    | WORKER      | 1    |
| 7   | G    | WORKER      | 4    |
| 8   | H    | BOSS        | 8    |
+-----+------+-------------+------+
8 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

An employee can't be the `BOSS` of themselves. Hence

```
mysql> INSERT INTO Employee VALUES ("8", "H", "BOSS",   "8");  
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.04 sec)
```

should be declined by some constraint. How can one add such a constraint?

If possible suggest without using a trigger.

Comment: You could with `CHECK (mssn <> ssn)` but check constraints are not implemented in MySQL.

Comment: In short, you can't, without major reconstruction of the table.

Comment: @ypercube : Thanks to answering me again! ... How to reconstruct? Please explain bit more.

Comment: .... or upgrade to a DBMS that does support check constraints (so pretty much every other DBMS)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name : So in MYSQL only trigger is an option?

Comment: Pretty much, yes.

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan: what exactly are your requirements/restrictions? Every `employee` can be either `'Owner'`, `'Boss'` or `'Worker'`? Can someone be both Boss and Worker? Are there other employee types? Everyone has a "manager" except owners?

Comment: @ypercube : The actual data base I am working with is consists of many columns... In this question I just wants that no one can insert a wrong tuple.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name : Please give me a suggestion on this question too

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13518890/which-update-is-faster-using-join-or-sequential

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This would be easily solved with a check constraint but these are not yet implemented in MySQL (they are just parsed for "compatibility reasons" during the `CREATE TABLE` definition and completely ignored after that.)

---

So, **solution 1** is rather obvious. Move to a DBMS that has `CHECK` constraint implemented, like SQL-Server, Oracle, Postgres, etc. (even MS-Access has them!):

```
ALTER TABLE Employee
  ADD CONSTRAINT Employee_cannot_be_Boss_of_himself
    CHECK (mssn <> ssn) ;
```

---

**Solution 2** is to drop the `designation` column altogether. From your description, all `'Owners'` have null `mssn` and all others have their "manager's" `ssn` stored in the `mssn` column.

After dropping that column, you can always calculate it in a view:

```
CREATE VIEW EmployeeDesignated AS
  SELECT ssn
       , name
       , CASE WHEN (mssn IS NULL OR mssn = ssn) 
                THEN 'OWNER'
              WHEN EXISTS (SELECT * FROM Employee ew WHERE ew.mssn = e.ssn)  
                THEN 'BOSS'
              ELSE 'WORKER'
         END AS designation
       , mssn
  FROM Employee AS e ;
```

This just enforces that when a new employee is inserted, if the `mssn` is same as the `ssn`, the employee is assigned as 'Owner'.

You may have performance issues though, depending on how you use the `designation` column. Views inside views or complex queries are not the best deal for MySQL's optimizer.

---

**Solution 3** is to emulate the `CHECK` constraint using the method described in this answer: [Check constraint does not work?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/22019/993)

This requires that you upgrade to either MySQL version 5.7 or to MariaDB 5.5.

---

**Solution 4** is to wait for them to be implemented. There are rumors (it's 2016 now) that they will be in the next version.

Comment: I `learn` something `new` from your answer. Thanks Lots ypercube.